# Where clause affecting two different select statements

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I need to count the payers and mortals separately who have a zip code of 44444. Their zip codes are stored in the same tables but their IDs are on two separate tables in many-to-many relationships. I have written this:

```
select count(mortal_zip) as "Mortals in 44444"
      ,count(payer_zip) as "Payers in 44444"
  from
      (select am.zip_code as mortal_zip
         from address am
         join mortal_address
           on mortal_address.address_id = am.address_id
         join mortal
           on mortal.mortal_id = mortal_address.mortal_id
        where trim(am.zip_code) = '44444'
       ) m,
      (select ap.zip_code as payer_zip
         from address ap
         join payer_address
           on payer_address.address_id = ap.address_id
         join payer
           on payer.payer_id = payer_address.payer_id
        where trim(ap.zip_code) = '44444'
       ) p;
```

I know this: There are no payers with a zip code of 44444 but there are 3 mortals with a zip code of 44444. For some reason I am getting that there are 0 mortals with a zip code of 44444. If I ask for just mortals in 44444, I get what I needed. If I ask for the count of mortals and a count of payers with 444444 I get 0 on both sides.

Additionally, I have tried re writing the whole thing with sub selects.

```
select count(m.mortal_zip) as "Mortals in 44444"
      ,count(p.payer_zip) as "Payers in 44444"
  from
      (select am.zip_code as mortal_zip
         from address am
        where trim(am.zip_code) = '44444'
          and am.address_id in
             (select mortal_address.address_id
                from mortal_address
               where mortal_address.mortal_id in
                  (select mortal.mortal_id
                     from mortal
                   )
              )
       ) m,
      (select ap.zip_code as payer_zip
         from address ap
        where trim(ap.zip_code) = '44444'
          and ap.address_id in
             (select payer_address.address_id
                from payer_address
               where payer_address.payer_id in
                    (select payer.payer_id
                       from payer
                    )
              ) 
       ) p;
```

I get the same result.

Why is the where function in a different select statement affecting the other select statement?

*Update*

I've re written the query but these two queries are returning different values.

This:

```
select m.mortal_zip as "Mortals in 44444"
      ,p.payer_zip as "Payers in 44444"
  from
      (select count(am.zip_code) as mortal_zip
         from address am
        where trim(am.zip_code) = '44444'
          and am.address_id in
             (select mortal_address.address_id
                from mortal_address
               where mortal_address.mortal_id in
                  (select mortal.mortal_id
                     from mortal
                   )
              )
       ) m,
      (select count(ap.zip_code) as payer_zip
         from address ap
        where trim(ap.zip_code) = '44444'
          and ap.address_id in
             (select payer_address.address_id
                from payer_address
               where payer_address.payer_id in
                    (select payer.payer_id
                       from payer
                    )
              ) 
       ) p;
```

Returns:

```
Mortals in 44444 Payers in 44444
---------------- ---------------
               3               0
```

This:

```
select mortal_zip as "Mortals in 44444"
      ,payer_zip as "Payers in 44444"
  from
      (select count(am.zip_code) as mortal_zip
         from address am
         join mortal_address
           on mortal_address.address_id = am.address_id
         join mortal
           on mortal.mortal_id = mortal_address.mortal_id
        where trim(am.zip_code) = '44444'
       ) m,
      (select count(ap.zip_code) as payer_zip
         from address ap
         join payer_address
           on payer_address.address_id = ap.address_id
         join payer
           on payer.payer_id = payer_address.payer_id
        where trim(ap.zip_code) = '44444'
       ) p;
```

Returns:

```
Mortals in 44444 Payers in 44444
---------------- ---------------
               5               0
```

Comment: Please try to avoid the join type you're doing there. Read up on cartesian joins. You're in effect doing a CROSS JOIN but because one side of your query is empty you're getting no results. What you want to do is use a base table then carry out a LEFT JOIN to each of the sub selects you've done. This will allow NULL values to be returned without suppressing data.

Comment: Why do you need to trim the zip code? Do you know or suspect it may have unnecessary spaces around it? If so, it is more efficient to use something like:  where am.zip_code like '%44444%'  - avoid wrapping a column value within a function whenever possible.

Comment: @mathguy The zip code field is a varchar datatype with 15 character spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Your query is trying to `JOIN` an empty result set with a result set that has three rows. Of course, this returns the empty result set. Instead, you could run subselects that get the `COUNT`s themselves, or alternatively:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(MA.address_id) AS "Mortals in 44444",
    COUNT(PA.address_id) AS "Payers in 44444"
FROM
    Address A
LEFT OUTER JOIN Mortal_Address MA ON MA.address_id = A.address_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN Payer_Address PA ON PA.address_id = A.address_id
WHERE
    A.zip_code = '44444'
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest doing this with a UNION to get the values you want, and then just SUM the values:

```
SELECT SUM(MORTAL_ZIP) AS MORTAL_ZIP,
       SUM(PAYER_ZIP) AS PAYER_ZIP
FROM (select COUNT(*) as mortal_zip,
             0 as payer_zip
        from address a
        inner join mortal_address ma
           on ma.address_id = a.address_id
        inner join mortal m
           on m.mortal_id = ma.mortal_id
        where trim(a.zip_code) = '44444'
      UNION ALL
      select 0 as mortal_zip,
             count(*) as payer_zip
        FROM address a
        inner join payer_address pa
          on pa.address_id = a.address_id
        inner join payer p
          on p.payer_id = pa.payer_id
        where trim(a.zip_code) = '44444')
```

Best of luck.

Answer (score -1):

I probably didn't need to ask Stack Overflow for this, but here is the answer that that I sought. Hope it helps who ever else may stubble upon this thread.

```
select m.mortal_zip as "Mortals in 44444"
      ,p.payer_zip as "Payers in 44444"
  from
      (select count(am.zip_code) as mortal_zip
         from address am
        where trim(am.zip_code) = '44444'
          and am.address_id in
             (select mortal_address.address_id
                from mortal_address
               where mortal_address.mortal_id in
                  (select mortal.mortal_id
                     from mortal
                   )
              )
       ) m,
      (select count(ap.zip_code) as payer_zip
         from address ap
        where trim(ap.zip_code) = '44444'
          and ap.address_id in
             (select payer_address.address_id
                from payer_address
               where payer_address.payer_id in
                    (select payer.payer_id
                       from payer
                    )
              ) 
       ) p;
```

I just needed to put `count` in the sub selects. Just as @TomH said.

Comment: This query is doing a lot of work for the benefit.  The first answer in the list will be much faster.  In fact, so will the second.

Comment: @TGray For my purposes, it works. Its a small data set and I was tight on time. I will revise it and probably accept one of the answers you refereed to. All though I couldn't help but ask how you could gauge the efficiency of my query just by looking at it.

Comment: Based on counts and subqueries against the same tables.  That is going to cause, at best, a hash on the queries and if the optimizer throws up its hands, some major scans.  Nothing personal.  I've been writing queries for a long time.  If you have a very small data set, it might work.  The trim on the zip code, unless you have a function based index, is going to ignore the index on that column.  In addition, data distribution against zip code is going to be small.  Add the "in" clauses and you are faced with, at best, partial scans.  Probably not an issue for your small data set.